# Need to have smooth scroll in mobile only project

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have an issue with scrolling. In our web project, our testers are raising issues for scrolling. They are scrolling up and down rapidly and by doing that, the text is getting blurred. Is there any fixes for this?
We are using only javascript and css. I found many plugins for jittery scroll but none of them seems to fix this problem.
Please provide a solution

Thanks and regards,
Anil Simon

Comment: Show us your code, please, we have no idea, what's happening without it

Comment: actually we have not implented anything so far for this issue.

Comment: So any new piece of code will be helpful :)

Comment: You can use chrome timeline tool, record a scrolling session and look for dropped frames
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool

Comment: _“They are scrolling up and down rapidly and by doing that, the text is getting blurred. Is there any fixes for this?”_ – I’d rather ask, is this a (real) problem that _needs_ fixing? I can get a lot of sites to behave weirdly, if I _provoke_ it by applying abnormal behavior.

Comment: This is infact not a real problem. But our product owner does not agree with us and hence we are forced into a corner in this regard :(

Comment: So any code fixes that can help will be immensly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use below css to resolve this

```
* {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```